# event.getparam('action').name is not working for lightning:datatable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable

**Component**

```
<lightning:datatable 
                         data="{! v.resources }" 
                         columns="{! v.mycolumns }" 
                         keyField="Id" 
                         onrowaction="{! c.handleRowAction }" 
                         hideCheckboxColumn="true" />
```

**Controller**

```
handleRowAction: function (component, event, helper) {
                var action = event.getParam('action');
                var row = event.getParam('row');
    }
```

[image]

Here as you can see, handleRowAction i am not getting the value of action variable.

I don't why its not working for me, as i have seen alot of blogs over it, every one is suggesting this method only.

Comment: Can you try putting `console.log(event.getParams())` before that and see exactly what data it has?

Comment: @RohitMourya I am getting same , what i am getting for action variable.

Comment: Do you have any working example for lightning:datatable which also works for Standalone Lightning App and lightning experience?

Comment: Not yet, let me try with an example in my org.

Comment: Okay, Take help from here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleDatatableInAction

Comment: Have you defined the rowactions using `helper.getRowActions.bind(this, cmp),`. Please post the whole javascript controller.

Comment: No, I am not using anything complex here, just have a button on datatable and tried to get its values.
but onrowaction="{! c.handleRowAction }" is not working properly.

Comment: If you will go through the documentation, in the helper class first they've defined the actions and then they are using it in the datatable. Without looking at all the code, it would be hard to tell exactly what went wrong.

Comment: component.set('v.resources',[
            
            {label:'SERVICE DATE', fieldName: 'dateOfService', type: 'text', sortable: false},
            {label:'CLAIM ID', fieldName: 'linkBtn', type: 'button',
             typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'claimId'},
                              name: { fieldName: 'claimId'}, 
                              title: { fieldName: 'claimId'},
                              value:{ fieldName: 'claimId'}
                             }
            }]);

I am doing this in controller and setting it as a button.

Comment: Add it in your question. So it will help other members of the community to answer your question.

Comment: My question is , are you able to get

**var action = event.getParam('action');
                var row = event.getParam('row');**

these values?

Comment: @SFDCDolphin, can you update your question with controller columns binding code what ever added in comment section indicates wrong format. if you add exact your code it'll help to resolve your issue